# Android - NullPointerException after trying to call getSerializableExtra() method (which it works)

Tags: android, serialization, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to understand how Java serialization works, so I'm trying to add to my own Android app the possibility to transfer two strings (First and Last Name, to be precise) and then displaying in another activity a simple 'welcome' message with both strings.
The things just start to get really weird because I actually manage to transfer the two strings, but when it comes to displaying them.. I "lose" them and I get a NullPointerException!

Anyway, here's the code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button personalData;
    protected String strUsername;
    private boolean isProfileReady;
    TextView welcome;
    protected SharedPreferences loginData;
    SharedPreferences wizardPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor wizardEditor;
    DataUser userData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
        personalData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.data);
        personalData.setText("Personal Data");
        personalData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WizardActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("profileReady", isProfileReady);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        loginData = getSharedPreferences("UserPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        wizardPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("USERDATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String value = loginData.getString("Username", null);
        welcome.setText("Welcome " + loginData.getString("Username", strUsername) + "!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            isProfileReady = true;
            personalData.setText("My Profile");
            welcome.setText("Welcome " + userData.getStrFName() + " " + userData.getStrLName() + "!");
        }

    }

}
```

WizardActivity.java

```
public class WizardActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SummaryFragment.Images {

    public DataUser userData;

    //region Variables
    Button go;
    WizardOne wizOne;
    WizardTwo wizTwo;
    WizardThree wizThree;
    SummaryFragment summaryFragment;
    Bitmap frontBitmap, backBitmap;
    SharedPreferences wizardPrefs;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    String pathOne, pathTwo;

    int currentPage = 1;

    public static final String FRONT_BITMAP_KEY = "frontBitmap", BACK_BITMAP_KEY = "backBitmap";

    boolean isProfileReady;
    //endregion

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        userData = new DatiUtente();
        isProfileReady = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("profileReady", false);

        Toast.makeText(this, "profileReady : " + isProfileReady, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        setContentView(R.layout.wizard_layout);
        go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);

        if (isProfileReady) {
            currentPage = 4;
            go.setText("Home");
            wizardPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("USERDATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
            summaryFragment = new SummaryFragment();
            summaryFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_layout, summaryFragment).commit();
        } else {
            wizOne = new WizardOne(userData);
            if (savedInstanceState == null)
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_layout, wizOne).commit();
        }

        go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isProfileReady) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    nextFragment();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void nextFragment() {

        switch (currentPage) {

            case 1:
                if (wizOne.validate()) {

                    wizTwo = new WizardTwo();
                    changeFragment(wizTwo, R.id.activity_layout);
                    currentPage++;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Riempire i campi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                if (wizTwo.validate()) {
                    wizThree = new WizardThree(getApplicationContext());
                    changeFragment(wizThree, R.id.activity_layout);
                    currentPage++;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Riempire i campi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                if (wizThree.validate()) {
                    bundle.putParcelable("frontBitmap", wizThree.getFrontBitmap());
                    bundle.putParcelable("backBitmap", wizThree.getBackBitmap());
                    summaryFragment = new SummaryFragment();
                    summaryFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    go.setText("Home");
                    changeFragment(summaryFragment, R.id.activity_layout);
                    currentPage++;
                }
                break;

            case 4:
                passImages();
              //  setResult(RESULT_OK);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SerializableWelcome.class);
                intent.putExtra("dataUser", userData);
                startActivity(intent);
             //   finish();
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }


    public void changeFragment(ValidateFragment f, int resource) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(resource, f);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();

    }

    public Bitmap getFrontBitmap() {
        return frontBitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getBackBitmap() {
        return backBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (currentPage > 1) {
            currentPage--;
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Bundle passImages() {
        bundle.getParcelable("frontBitmap");
        bundle.getParcelable("backBitmap");
        return bundle;
    }
}
```

SerializableWelcome.java

```
public class SerializableWelcome extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView showName;
    DataUser userData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_services_main);

        showName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeFromSummary);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            userData = (DataUser) intent.getSerializableExtra("dataUser");
        }
        showName.setText("Welcome " + userData.getStrFName() + " " + userData.getStrLName() + "!");
    }
}
```

DataUser.java

```
public class DataUser implements Parcelable {

    String strFName, strLName, strFisCode, strBirth, strCity, strZip, strProv, strCC, strIban, strMail;

    public DataUser(){}

    protected DataUser(Parcel in) {

        //region in.readString()
        strFName = in.readString();
        strLName = in.readString();
        strFisCode = in.readString();
        strBirth = in.readString();
        strCity = in.readString();
        strZip = in.readString();
        strProv = in.readString();
        strCC = in.readString();
        strIban = in.readString();
        strMail = in.readString();
        //endregion

    }

    public static final Creator<DataUser> CREATOR = new Creator<DataUser>() {
        @Override
        public DataUser createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new DataUser(in);
        }

        @Override
        public DataUser[] newArray(int size) {
            return new DataUser[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        //region dest.writeString()
        dest.writeString(strFName);
        dest.writeString(strLName);
        dest.writeString(strFisCode);
        dest.writeString(strBirth);
        dest.writeString(strCity);
        dest.writeString(strZip);
        dest.writeString(strProv);
        dest.writeString(strCC);
        dest.writeString(strIban);
        dest.writeString(strMail);
        //endregion

    }

    //region Getter and Setter
    public String getStrFName() {
        return strFName;
    }

    public void setStrFName(String strFName) {
        this.strFName = strFName;
    }

    public String getStrLName() {
        return strLName;
    }

    public void setStrLName(String strLName) {
        this.strLName = strLName;
    }

    public String getStrFisCode() {
        return strFisCode;
    }

    public void setStrFisCode(String strFisCode) {
        this.strFisCode = strFisCode;
    }

    public String getStrBirth() {
        return strBirth;
    }

    public void setStrBirth(String strBirth) {
        this.strBirth = strBirth;
    }

    public String getStrCity() {
        return strCity;
    }

    public void setStrCity(String strCity) {
        this.strCity = strCity;
    }

    public String getStrZip() {
        return strZip;
    }

    public void setStrZip(String strZip) {
        this.strZip = strZip;
    }

    public String getStrProv() {
        return strProv;
    }

    public void setStrProv(String strProv) {
        this.strProv = strProv;
    }

    public String getStrCC() {
        return strCC;
    }

    public void setStrCC(String strCC) {
        this.strCC = strCC;
    }

    public String getStrIban() {
        return strIban;
    }

    public void setStrIban(String strIban) {
        this.strIban = strIban;
    }

    public String getStrMail() {
        return strMail;
    }

    public void setStrMail(String strMail) {
        this.strMail = strMail;
    }
    //endregion

}
```

Comment: `DataUser` is not `Serializable` but ...

Comment: `getparcelableextra`

Comment: @Spartan Thanks! :) 
I guess it was a dumb question from the very beginning.. D:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how you should pass and pull Parcelable object:

```
// Pass
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("name_of_extra", myParcelableObject);

// and then pull them:
Intent i = getIntent();
MyParcelable myParcelableObject = (MyParcelable) i.getParcelableExtra("name_of_extra");
```